# Why is accepts_nested_attributes_for not working as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to figure out why my create is not working. If I have the following two models below

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_template
  has_many :presentations, through: :product_presentations
  has_many :product_presentations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_presentations

  validates :start_date, :product_template_id, presence: true
  validates :start_date, uniqueness: true
end


class ProductPresentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :presentation

  validates_presence_of :product_id, :course_id, :presentation_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :presentation_id, :scope => :product_id
end
```

And I enter the following into my console.

```
product = Product.new(
{"start_date"=>"Sat, 06 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0200", 
"product_template_id"=>"5", "product_presentations_attributes"=>{
  "0"=>{"course_id"=>"1", "presentation_id"=>"1"}, 
  "1"=>{"course_id"=>"2", "presentation_id"=>"2"}}})
```

It should save, but I get the error below

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f9eaeb9d698 @base=#<Product id: nil, product_template_id: 5, start_date: "2014-09-05 22:00:00", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"product_presentations.product_id"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Now I understand that there is not product_id in the product_presentations_attributes hash, but I thought this would be rails automigically populated because it's being created via the product.

I had this working and now I can't figure out how I messed it up. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool ... after posting this, reading over my own post I tried to remove the validation for the product_id presence.

This seems to fix the error.

I am guessing that this is a limitation of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in rails - the parent object cannot have it's foreign key validated in the model.